# Applying angle addition formulas for subtraction

Tags: trigonometry

The angle addition formula says that:

$\sin(\phi + \theta) = \sin(\phi) \cdot \cos(\theta) + \cos(\phi) \cdot \sin(\theta)$

Why are the following steps valid?:

$\sin(\phi − \theta) = \sin(\phi) \cdot \cos(−\theta) + \cos(\phi) \cdot \sin(−\theta)= \sin(\phi) \cdot \cos(\theta) − \cos(\phi) \cdot \sin(\theta)$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\cos(\theta)$ is an even function while $\sin(\theta)$ is an odd function.

Hence:

$$\cos(-\theta) = \cos(\theta),$$

while

$$\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta).$$

(See this Wikipedia link on [Even and odd functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) for more information.)

Answer (score 1):

They're valid because of the following identities:

- $\qquad\sin(-\theta) \equiv -\sin(\theta) \qquad\text{since sin is an}$ [odd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions) function.
- $\qquad \cos(-\theta) \equiv \cos(\theta) \qquad\text{since cos is an} $ [even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even_functions) function.

---

The $\equiv$ symbol means "is equal to for **all** (permitted) values of $\ \theta$".

Answer (score 0):

They are valid because $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x) \forall_{x \in [0, 2\pi]}$ (sinus is an *odd* function) and $\cos(-x) = \cos(x) \forall_{x \in [0, 2\pi]}$ (cosine is an *even* function). You can see this by looking at sinus and cosine graphics.